# sentential use of "such as"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, as

Is it possible for "such as" to modify a whole sentence?

Example:

> At times, his life is threatened, such as when he had to climb down
>   the tunnel submerged in water.

Is it grammatical? Is it natural use?

Comment: I would take that *such ... as ...* to modify *times*: "His life is threatened at such times as [the time] when he had to &c".

Comment: @StoneyB Is it ungrammatical for "such as" to modify  a sentence or a clause?

Comment: @StoneyB I found this sentence on COCA: _His work on the seventh floor of a drab building in the Brussels suburbs can be exciting, **such as** when he was translating documents on the official EU position on Ukraine during the Kyiv protests in 2014._ I don't think it's modifying a noun?

Comment: In that case you're dealing with a colloquial use of *such as* = *for instance*; but in formal use I'd just use *as*, without *such*.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with the sentence presented by the OP. Look at another example as follows:

When I get tired, such as when I am working on my computer, I turn to biscuits (Collins Dictionary).